# Cubic Equations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Using the formula from https://engineersfield.com/cubic-equation-formula/:

```py
class CubicEquation():
    def __init__(self,a,b,c,d):
        '''initialize constants and formula'''
        q = (3*c - b**2) / 9
        r = -27*d + b*(9*c - 2*b**2)
        discriminant = q**3 + r**2
        s = r + sqrt(discriminant)
        t = r - sqrt(discriminant)
        term1 = sqrt(3 * ((-t + s) / 2))
        r13 = 2 * sqrt(q)

        self.cubic_equation = [\
            '-term1 + r13*cos(q**3 / 3)',\
            '-term1 + r13*cos(q**3 + (2 * pi)/3)',\
            '-term1 + r13*cos(q**3 + (4 * pi)/3)'\
            ]
    def solve(self):
        *--snip--*
```

and then later calling it with `answer = eval(self.cubic_equation[index])`

when calling this formula with args `(1,1,1,1)`, I receive the solution:
`-6.803217085397121, -8.226355957420402, -8.208435953185608`
and yes I have triple-checked my formulas with those on the site.

What is the correct code for this function, and what went wrong with my current program?

Comment: This is not *technically* an answer to your question, but have you considered just using [numpy roots](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)? `np.roots([1,1,1,1])` yields `[-1.00000000e+00+0.j -7.77156117e-16+1.j -7.77156117e-16-1.j]`, i.e. [-1,+ *i* ,- *i* ], as [expected](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1*x%5E3+%2B+1*x%5E2+%2B+1*x++%2B1)

Comment: I'm probably going too deep into this rabbit hole but help me understand the notation because complex numbers are notated `a + b*i` and not `Xe+Y+Z.j`.

Comment: This may seem confusing at first, but it's simply a mixture of [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) where `0.001 == 1*10^-3 == 1e-3`, [i.e. in the example above, `-7.77156117e-16` is the *very, very small* **real part** of the number] and numpy's way of writing imaginary numbers (using j, not i): `a+b j`. You can extract the real and imaginary parts using `np.real()` and `np.imag()`, i.e. `print(np.real(1.0e-3 + 1.0j))` yields `0.001`.

Comment: That formula is highly suspect: I'd recommend looking for alternatives. For one thing, it claims to present a solution to `ax3 + bx2 + cx + d = 0`, but `a` isn't used anywhere in that solution. For another, the usual trigonometric formula necessarily includes an `arccos` term as well as a `cos` term. Then there's the rather odd use of `(-t + s) / 2` as a complicated way to say `sqrt(discriminant)`. And let's not get into the use of a capital `Π` ...

Comment: You are right, I probably should not have trusted that, I'm just going for numpy.roots